# array index out of bound java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, listiterator

Let's say `numberTracker = {1,15,6,8}` and `numberString = {1,1,5,6,8}`. Each number in `numberString` has its own tile. 
I'm try to set for example 1,5 to the same tile color since it is equal to 15 in `numberTracker` while `tileIterator` contains the same length as `numberString`.The code works perfectly and does what is is suppost to do. However I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5`

```
ListIterator < String > nmbTracker = numberTracker.listIterator();
ListIterator < Tile > tileIterator = tiles.listIterator();
Tile t;

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

while (nmbTracker.hasNext()) {

    if (numberTracker.get(x).equals(numberString.get(y))) {

        t = tileIterator.next();
        t.setColor(tilePanel2.changeColour());
        if (numberTracker.size() - 1 != x) {
            x++;
        }
        if (numberString.size() - 1 != y) {
            y++;
        }


    } else {
        x++;
        t = tileIterator.next();
        t.setColor(tilePanel2.changeColour());
        Color color = t.getColor();
        t = tileIterator.next();
        t.setColor(color);
        y++;
        y++;


    }

    repaint();
}
```

Comment: why don't you debug and see by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well. That is what happens when you try to access index 5 in a list that has 4 elements in it. You are using the iterator's `hasNext()` to see if there are any `next` values available, yet you switch over to using `get(x)` to access the list values. **Pick one**.

If you want to stick to the `get(x)`, get rid of the `hasNext()` and replace it with `while(x<4 && y<5)`, so that the list accesses don't go out of bounds.

If you want the `iterator`, instead of using `get(x)`, use the iterator's `next()` method.

Using both interchangeably is not good, at least in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the smoking gun:

```
y++;
y++;
```

Next time around, you'll be one more along than the list you're checking.